# How to animate zooming in Android

Tags: android, pdfview

I'm developing an Android application, I used this library

> barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.3.0

I have to implement a simple animation, this is the code that I have implemented:

```
private void selectArea(){
    /* Stop movement, jump to page 2, disable all action on PDFView*/
    pdfView.stopFling();
    pdfView.jumpTo(2);
    pdfView.setEnabled(false);
    pdfView.zoomWithAnimation(0, 1500, (float) 1.95);      
}


private void resetAnimation() {
   pdfView.resetZoomWithAnimation();
}
```

I need to select a certain area, reset the zoom and select again the area, so the problem is :

When I call selectarea () function shows the area that I want to show, when it resetarea call () the zoom is restored, if i call again the selectarea function the pdfView.resetZoomWithAnimation() call is ignored, and I don't understand why.

Pseudocode of my app.

```
selectArea();
//do stuff
resetAnimation()
selectArea();
```

Comment: please post your solution in an answer and remove it from the question

Answer (score 1):

**** SOLUTION ****

After hours of attempts I found a solution of my problem:

```
private void selectAreaToSign(){
    /* Stop movement, jump to page 2, disable all action on PDFView*/
    pdfView.stopFling();
    pdfView.clearFocus();
    pdfView.jumpTo(2);
    pdfView.setEnabled(false);
    pdfView.clearAnimation();
    pdfView.clearFocus();

    if(isFirstTime){
        pdfView.zoomWithAnimation(0, 1700, (float) 2.00);
    }else{
        resetAnimation();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pdfView.zoomWithAnimation(4500, 1700, (float) 2.00);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

private void resetAnimation() {
    pdfView.resetZoomWithAnimation();
    sv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pdfView.zoomTo(1);
}
```